# How to detect changes of a list whithin a Python class, or why does "setter" not trigger

Tags: python, class, getter-setter

I would like to have a list in a Python class. Whenever an element in the list is changed I need to run some logic. I'm pretty new to classes in python and my approach with the setter might be pretty naive. This is what makes intuitive sense to me:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self._R = [False]*16

    @property
    def R(self):
        return self._R

    @R.setter
    def R(self,a):
        print('Why do I not get reached?')
        self._R = a

W = test()
W.R[0] = True
```

But the setter never gets triggered. If you could give me a notch in the right direction, I would be very great full.

Comment: You're not setting `W.R`. You're setting a list element. `W.R`'s setter isn't involved in that - setting a list element uses the list's `__setitem__`.

Comment: Only the getter was called. `W.R[0] = True` is the same as `tmp = W.R;tmp[0] = True`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Am I right to assume that when I use the ```__setitem__```    that i then would have to treat the whole class as a list and assign values like ```W[0] = Ture```, for example

Comment: @tdelaney is there a way to call the setter as well?

Comment: You don't *want* to call the setter; that would replace the 16-element list completely with some other type, e.g. `W.R = "something else"`. Your class `test` has  nothing to do with assignments to its attribute, aside from providing the list on which `__setitem__` is called.

Comment: Its the list that's being updated - you could potentially create a class that inherits from list but you'd have to reimplement a lot of its methods to detect all the ways it could be changed - its generally a difficult task. Or, you could write a function that does set setting `def set_R(self, index, value): self._R[index] = value`. You could even def `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` so that `W[0] = True` does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new List-like class that takes a callback function and executes it whenever the list is changed:

```
class CallbackList:  # PEP-8 style suggests UpperCase class names
    def __init__(self, callback=None):
        self._list = [False]
        self._callback = callback  # Python functions are first-class objects just like ints, strings, etc, so this is completely legal

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self._list[index] = value
        if self._callback:
            self._callback()  # Executes the callback function whenever a value is set

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._list[index]


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.callback_list = CallbackList(callback=self.foo)

    def foo(self):
        print("You changed the list!")


W = Test()
W.callback_list[0] = True  # This prints "You changed the list!"
```

Note that this still won't catch every possible change. For example:

```
W = Test()
some_list = [1, 2, 3]

W.callback_list[0] = some_list  # This triggers the callback function
print(W.callback_list[0])  # [1, 2, 3]

some_list.append(4)  # This does NOT trigger the callback function!
print(W.callback_list[0])  # [1, 2, 3, 4] !
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put in your answer it is really appreciated. I will try implementing it and then let you know if it worked!

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thank you! There is one thing I'm not sure if i understand it correctly: In the line  ```self.callback_list = CallbackList(callback=self.foo)``` what is actually passed to the new instance of  ```CallbackList``` is it only the function ```foo``` or the whole instance that created it? I.e. could foo change local attributes of the instance W?

Comment: Yes, foo can change elements of the specific W instance it belongs to. Note that it’s referred to as “self.foo”, where “self” is the specific instance of the Test class rather than the class itself. If you only wanted there to be a single foo function across multiple instances, you could mark it as “@staticmethod”

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write code according to @user2357112supportsMonica comments:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 1

    def foo(self):
        print(self.A)

    class R_Class():
        def __init__(self):
            self._R = [False]*16

        def __setitem__(self,index,value):
            self._R[index] = value
            test.foo() #Here I need to call foo somehow
        def __getitem__(self,index):
            return self._R[index]
    R = R_Class()


W = test()
W.R[0] = True
```

But this approach leads to another problem, is there a way to properly call the foo function from within the sub class?